# Can I find out when a rom or recovery was installed?

Tags: custom-roms, recovery-mode, clockworkmod-recovery, rom

I have **purchased a totally new phone (G2)** and when I got it, it was already **with a custom ROM** with SU and a **clockwork recovery**. I have a receipt from the purchase with date and time. I need to be able to prove that the ROM and recovery were installed before I made the purchase.

How can I find time of rom or recovery installation?

Comment: It will probably be hard to prove without a doubt that you didn't install the ROM. Any timestamps on the phone can be edited with root.

Comment: Files are rewrote with updated timestamps as well. I researched for a couple of hours, found a bunch of hooey. Wasn't able to find a conclusive answer for actual system creation time on device.